# Hard Incoming API limits for Unlimited Edition orgs

Tags: apex

In Salesforce Unlimited edition the [documentation](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm#rate_limits_title) says we have Unlimited API Calls. But in System Overview it says we have got only 200000. Which MAX API limits should we assume? It will impact the further design architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Unlimited" is there for the higher or maximum limit. This is how it works:

Each different license type has a number of callouts allocated, which count towards the total callouts in your org. For an example in your Unlimited Edition org, 1 Salesforce license can make up to 5000 callouts per 24 hours. But because you have a **"minimum" of 15,000** - this will be your limit.

**What happens if you have 1500 Salesforce licenses?**

This is where the "Maximum" limit kicks in. In an Enterprise Edition org where with 1 Salesforce license you can make up to 1000 callouts, the maximum callouts limit per 24 hours will be **1,000,000 (maximum)** and not 1,500,000 (1500 licenses * 1000 callouts per license) - because it's enforced by the platform as per [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm#rate_limits_title).

However, in your case (Unlimited Edition), because the maximum limit it's "Unlimited", you'll be able to make **1,500,000** callouts. If you have 3000 Salesforce licenses, you can make **15,000,000** callouts and so forth. The point is, you don't have a maximum limit, you can make as many callouts as the number licenses you have in the org multiplied by their type limit.

**Different License Types**

Note that different types of licenses have different callout counts. They're specified in the "API Calls Per License Type" column in the documentation. In your case (Unlimited Edition), if you have 5 Salesforce licenses and 10 Force.com - One App licenses, you'll have a maximum callouts limit of (5 * 5000 + 10 * 200) **27,000** callouts per 24 hours.

**Why do I have 200000 limit?**

This is your maximum limit based on your number of licenses in your org (and their type). This will be the case if you have 400 Salesforce licenses for argument sake. So technically you're restricted by this limit (unless you buy more licenses).

Comment: Can i increase the API limits? like if i want 50lacs API calls?

Comment: From the documentation - "If you need a higher limit and you don't want to purchase additional user licenses or upgrade to Performance Edition, you can purchase additional API calls. For more information, contact your account representative."